# Why menu items in android studio don't work on click?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

I'm developing a project on android and completely new to this. I had made a drawer menu with some of menu items. Now when i want to put another activity on click from menu items, the drawer closes automatically, it doesn't work. Here

```
private DrawerLayout mdrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mdrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mdrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    mdrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mdrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    mdrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mdrawerToggle);

    mdrawerToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mdrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id == R.id.setup){
        Intent csetup = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Subactivity.class);
        startActivity(csetup);

        return false;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
Add below code in your `onCreate` method:

```
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Implement lister in your mainactivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
```

And after that in your onNavigationItemSelected method look like this:

```
   @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.setup) {
        //call new activity
         }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
     }
```

Hope this may help you

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are overriding the wrong method. You have to override onNavigationItemSelected() for drawer, instead of onOptionsItemSelected() which is for top-right settings menu. See the following code for reference:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.setup) {
             Intent csetup = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Subactivity.class);
             startActivity(csetup);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First find the view for you `NavigationView` using `findViewById` method like below-`NavigationView navView=(NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navView)`
then use this.

```
navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.setup) {
                Intent csetup = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Subactivity.class);
                startActivity(csetup);
            }

            return false;

        }
    });
```

then it will work.. `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` is used to get the access to the `MenuItems` we have inflated on toolbar or on other layouts using `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method.